# Have any major universities around the world announced a transition to a remote-first model?

Tags: remote-work

Numerous companies around the world have announced they're getting rid of office space and allowing their employees to work from anywhere in the world, [if their roles allows it](https://www.cnn.com/2021/05/05/tech/google-office-remote-work-pandemic/index.html). Have any major universities around the world announced a similar transition? It would be impossible for, say, cancer research to move "into the cloud" but there's no reason why theoretical math research would need any in-person interactions.

Obviously there's still the question of how to teach students but this was also executed successfully (in terms of technical feasibility, how good the outcomes have been [is unclear to me](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/168165/did-any-universities-publish-an-official-analysis-on-how-successful-remote-learn)) during the pandemic so in theory an institution might choose to shutdown large swaths of their campus altogether or switch to a hybrid model.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/168129/do-universities-make-fully-remote-contracts

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124737/discussion-on-question-by-jonathanreez-have-any-major-universities-around-the-wo).