# Did any universities publish an official analysis on how successful remote learning has been during the pandemic?

Tags: covid-19, remote-work

Most universities around the world have now completed at least a year in remote-first mode due to the COVID pandemic. Some countries have been lucky enough to avoid/supress a major explosion of cases (China, New Zealand, Australia) but European and North American institutions have definitely been severely restricted in how much they could do in-person.

Did any universities publish an overview of how successful remote learning has been, according to whatever metrics they find important? I.e. graduation rates, median test scores, number of research grants approved, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure what metrics would make a good comparison. Grants approved will remain stable, because granting agencies have the same fixed pot of money to distribute. Most test scores are normalized in some way, whether via official grading on the curve or via more subjective subconscious marker adjustments. I guess a change in graduation rates might tell you something, but I've not heard of them really changing anywhere.

Comment: This will be an interesting study.  However, at least at my university and many in Australia, people are in survival mode; too busy fighting for their job, and making the transition to an online setting, which is made even more challenging if you are not too good with computers.  Also, given the huge job cuts, many of us have double or triple the usual load.

Comment: An interesting question, indeed, but I suspect many of the people who have the information (with whatever metrics) have incentives to not be forthright...

Comment: Entirely anecdotal 'evidence' from one undergrad and one grad student - remote learning is horrible. Also unlikely that universities would knowingly penalize students (e.g. graduating fewer of them than normal) for suffering through Covid times.

Comment: @JonCuster I know a person who was able to: 1) move back to his parents house 2) quit their near minimum wage job since they didn't need the money anymore 3) stop wasting time on commuting to class/work. Combined their productivity insanely shot up. Would probably be different for someone fully funded by their parents and living near campus in a private apartment.

Comment: I expect it to take a couple of years, at least, before any studies get published.

Comment: Student course evaluation scores are a likely metric.

Comment: Also remote assessment means utterly rampant cheating, so you can’t corollate scores on assessment to any meaningful learning.

Comment: @Buffy I know an academic at my university who's looking for a PhD student to study this exact topic.